# Win32 event name visibility only to own process

Tags: winapi, events

I would like my named events to be visible/openable only inside my process.

I currently create events with `CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, "my event name");` and they are visible and settable by other processes, which seems dangerous to me. I am afraid that if another application uses the same event name by accident, the two applications would interfere with each other.

How can I let my event be accessible only to the process they are created in? Or what would be the appropriate safe use of event names when we don't need interprocess communication?

Comment: you not need named event. if you want several threads use it - pass event handle inside parameters of thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows security is account-based. You can protect your event object from other user accounts, but not from other processes using the same account in the current login session.

Note that if you are only worried about inadvertent collisions rather than malicious, you can use a private object namespace (look up [`CreatePrivateNamespace()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createprivatenamespacea)). You would create a boundary descriptor, add your account's SID to that descriptor, then use the descriptor to create a private namespace, then finally create any kernel objects you wish to protect from collision within that namespace.

This only protects against accidental collision, though, as any other process running in your account could open the namespace to access the objects within it.

I should add that if you are wanting names that are visible but are not likely to collide, you could choose string formatted GUIDs as your names (for example, the common pattern used to ensure that only one instance of an executable is running is to create a named kernel object and check `GetLastError()` for `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS`). GUIDs work very well for that, as they are extremely unlikely to accidentally collide, and far easier to use than a private namespace.

Comment: This is described in more detail on MSDN, see [Object Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/object-namespaces).

Answer (score 2):

> I would like my named events to be visible/openable only inside my process.

[Kernel Object Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/termserv/kernel-object-namespaces) don't work that way.  If you assign a name to a kernel object, like an event object, then that object is discoverable by other processes, and potentially accessible (depending on the security you assign to the object when you create it).

> How can I let my event be accessible only to the process they are created in?

If you want your kernel objects to be accessible only to your process that creates them, then DON'T ASSIGN NAMES TO THEM at the kernel level.  It is as simple as that.  If you need to refer to the objects by name in your code, create your own lookup mapping to handle that, such as with C++'s `std::map` class, or C#'s `Dictionary` class, or whatever your chosen programming language actually provides.  For example:

```cpp
std::map<std::string, HANDLE> my_events;
...
my_events["my event name"] = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, NULL);
// use my_events["my event name"] as needed...
```